# How to decide whether light shows particle of wave nature?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

I have had this question for quite a time. I have recently studied about photoelectric effect. I was taught that light consisted of particles called photons that carried inherent energy with it, that is decided by Planck's formula E=hf. I am also aware of electromagnetic theory of light, where light is considered as wave of oscillating electric and magnetic fields, where each field regenerates each other due to Ampere's law and Faraday's law.

However, if I try to apply wave nature of light on the photoelectric scenario, the electrons would experience electromagnetic forces, which are oscillatory in nature. I would get the electrons to *simply osscilate* rather than eject out of the metal. The only way an electron to eject out by this approach is  by some form of "resonance" with the light that causes large amplitudes of vibration.

But however, we see that electrons are continuosly ejected out. Electromagnetic property of light seems to be absent here.

So my question is, **In a given scenario, how do we decide if light exibits its particle nature or wave nature**

Thanks to those who can satisfy my query.